# How to change inputs in the middle of a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

The script loops through the first 10 lines in the text file and waits for 1 minute before moving to the next 10.

Is it possible to ask for `batchSize` and `delayInMinutes` before moving to the next batch?

```
import time

count = 0
hosts = open("hosts.txt", "r+")

batchSize = int(input("batchSize (default: 10) : ") or "10")
delayInMinutes = int(input("delayInMinutes (default: 1) : ") or "5")

for host in hosts:
    instanceId = host.strip()
    count = count + 1
    print(count, instanceId)
    if count % batchSize == 0:
        time.sleep(delayInMinutes * 60)
        # Test case 1
        # batchSize = int(input("batchSize (default: 10) : ") or "10")
        # delayInMinutes = int(input("delayInMinutes (default: 5) : ") or "5")
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
```

Output:

```
batchSize (default: 10) : 2
delayInMinutes (default: 5) : 1

1 05a8f8aa-8778-4cb8-b4a5-8a38700d3da6
2 06b25cee-6c0f-4516-9330-19a50f6a8f99
batchSize (default: 10) : 3
delayInMinutes (default: 5) : 1
3 0f4b033e-856b-4d75-b8fe-5e8a0d1c577d
batchSize (default: 10) : 2
delayInMinutes (default: 5) : 1
4 1545f282-d0bb-4001-b7f9-98255f2fcfaa
batchSize (default: 10) : 5
delayInMinutes (default: 5) : 1
5 2a9cc516-c75e-4e40-860b-5f77fc9a5a8a
```

Comment: Yes, just ask to input values after `time.sleep(delayInMinutes * 60)` again.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that before and some loops are not aligned to the inputs. but i guess that's the best we could do. isn't it? added the output.

Comment: `if count % batchSize == 0:` is the wrong math if `batchSize` is not a fixed value. You could store the current `count` plus new `batchSize` in a variable (e.g. `next_stop`), and then use `if count == next_stop:`.